# Generating $n\times n$ random matrix with rank $n/2$ using matlab

Tags: matlab

Can we  generate $n \times n$  random matrix having any desired rank?
I have to generate a $n\times n$ random matrix having rank $n/2$.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generate $U,V$ random matrices of size $n \times n/2$, then *almost surely* $A = U \cdot V^T$ is of rank $n/2$.

Comment: (+1) Unless, of course, $n$ is odd. `;-)`

Comment: @user17762 Thank you very much. It works. Can we say anything about what distribution will it follow?